# How to reduce space between name and address on a latex resume?

Tags: spacing, cv, resume

I'm writing a resume using Latex and I would like to reduce the space between the line `\name` and the line `address`. How to do so ?
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} % Document margins
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}} 
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{M\MakeLowercase{y}  N\MakeLowercase{ame}} % Your name
\address{address.} % Your address
\address{+XX... \\ myemail@email.com}  % Your phone number and email

\begin{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

I used the [Medium Length Professional CV](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv) as the source for `resume.cls`.

The gap between the name and the rest of the "title" is given by `\nameskip`, which defaults to `\bigskip`. Here are some sample changes:

- Default (`\newcommand{\nameskip}{\bigskip}`):

  [image]
- `\renewcommand{\nameskip}{\medskip}`:

  [image]
- `\renewcommand{\nameskip}{\smallskip}`:

  [image]
- `\renewcommand{\nameskip}{}` (no space):

  [image]
- `\renewcommand{\nameskip}{\vspace{5\baselineskip}}` (large positive gap):

  [image]

Add your choice just before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: My full respect for finding the right template :-)